# Как правильно передать int переменную в хранилище SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android

Для настроек приложения (изменения размера текста) использую ListPreference

```html
<ListPreference
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_text"
        android:defaultValue="18"
        android:entries="@array/Set_string"
        android:entryValues="@array/Set_Values"
        android:summary="%s"
        android:key="size"
        android:title="@string/Сhoose_Size">
    </ListPreference>
```

Выбор делаю с помощью массива string-array (по другому в документации никак):

```html
<string name="size" translatable="false">size</string>
    <string-array name="Set_string">
        <item>14</item>
        ...................
        <item>24</item>
        <item>26</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="Set_Values">
        <item>14</item>
       .....................
        <item>24</item>
        <item>26</item>
    </string-array>
```

Соответственно в хранилище data/data/....preferences имеем:

```html
<string name="size">18</string>
```

А должно быть так:

```html
<int name="size" value="18" />
```

Соответственно вопросы:
1. как правильно передать int переменную в хранилище SharedPreferences с помощью моего выбора через ListPreference?
2. на каком этапе это делать (когда записываю в хранилище или когда получаю из него)? Имею несколько активитити/фрагментов где будет изменятьсься размер текста.
Я вызываю sp и меняю размер текста вот так:

```html
TextView Kondaktext1 = findViewById(R.id.Kondaktext1);
            String text = "\t\t\tНепереможний Воєводо і Господи, пекла Переможцю,   ........<br />";                   
            Kondaktext1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, sp.getInt("size", 18));
            Kondaktext1.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: А где в вопросе SharedPreferences?

Comment: Не пойму о чем вы спрашиваете? Хранилище настроек - это и есть SharedPreferences. Там у меня хранятся использыемые настройки. Я только учусь, поправьте если что не так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два варианта:

1. написать свой класс-альтернативу или наследник `ListPreference`, в котором сохранять `int`.
2. брать из `SharedPreferences` запись как строку и преобразовывать в `int` по месту использования.

Второе проще в реализации:

```
TextView Kondaktext1 = findViewById(R.id.Kondaktext1);
String text = "\t\t\tНепереможний Воєводо і Господи, пекла Переможцю,   ........<br />";
String prefSize = sp.getString("size", null);
int ts = prefSize == null ? 18 : Integer.parseInt(prefSize);
Kondaktext1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, ts);
Kondaktext1.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ!!!

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть `key` это ключ по которому мы находим настройку.
Она кладется туда автоматически при выборе. 
Вам остается лишь только эту настройку достать в нужный момент в активити, во фрагменте либо использовать отдельный класс для этого.

Примерно так в активити, там где нужно выдернуть:

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private int textSize;


sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
textSize= sharedPreferences.getInt(key, defaultValue);
```

Все, теперь у вас есть выбранный размер текста. Далее

```
textView.setTextSize(textSize);
```

Подробнее об этом можно почитать здесь:

[хабр](https://habr.com/ru/post/112100/),

[стартандроид](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/135-urok-72-preferences-spisok-ekrany-i-kategorii.html),

[Сайт Александра Климова](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/preferences_framework.php)

Comment: Вы передаете string array. На выходе соответственно получаете String

Comment: Я читал эти все ссылки: 1. Климов делает по-старинке, и немного неправильно. 2. startandroid делают это через кнопки (поэтому я их не могу понять). habr - просто выводит на экран настройки и ни слова о string или int.
А по поводу кода, что вы написали - я так и делаю в активити, но у меня выдает ошибку, поскольку в sharedPreferences у меня лежит string, который туда положил ListPreference. Вот мне и нужно преобразовать string в int.

Comment: @Олександр можно ложить не stting array а int.  Или же можно выполнить преобразование типов на выходе

Comment: Вот об этом я и прошу помощи. Согласно документации ListPreference ложит только string. Значит остается второе: преобразовать string в int, а как это делать я неумею.

Comment: `int number = Integer.parseInt(string);`

Comment: Спасибо, я так пробовал, прописал в активити и у меня выдает ошибку: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null     Я наверное что-то не так делаю.

Comment: Наверное. Строку получаете так: `sp.getString("size", "18")`? Если да, то проверьте её на `null` - если `null` ставьте дефолтное значение сразу, если нет преобразуйте.

Comment: Нет, в коде выше я указывал 'Kondaktext1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, sp.getInt("size", 18));'

Comment: И где здесь преобразование?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98531/discussion-between--and-woesss).